# Is it possible to sort elements in a ToManyField attribute using TastyPie?

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have a REST API using Django Tastypie. Given the following code

The models

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    # class body omitted, it has a content and an author


class Comment(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name="comments")
    published = models.DateTimeField()
    # rest of class omitted
```

The resources

```
class CommentResource:
    # omitted

class BlogPostResource(ModelResource):

    comments = fields.ToManyField("resources.CommentResource",
        attribute="comments")
```

When I ask for a blogpost I get something like:

```
GET: api/blogpost/4/

{
   'content' : "....",
   'author' : "....",
   'comments' : ['api/comment/4/', 'api/comment/5']
}
```

However, the comments are not necessarily sorted by any field. I would like to make sure they are sorted by a specific key (`published`)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the field in `BlogPostResource` to the following:

```
class BlogPostResource(ModelResource):

    comments = fields.ToManyField("resources.CommentResource",
        attribute=lambda bundle: bundle.obj.comments.all().order_by("published"))
```

Comment: If I do this the comments are not paginated

Answer (score 2):

You could also try adding an ordering in the actual Comment Model (not in the tastypie Comment ModelResource):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name="comments")
    published = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['published']
```